# LEFT JOIN Statement with ON and WHERE

Tags: sql

I tried to understand how ON and WHERE would affect the execution of the statement but no luck..

I have this statement which gives me the expected result:

```
     SELECT  DISTINCT u1.email
     FROM user u1
     LEFT JOIN user u2
     ON u1.email = u2.email
     WHERE u1.id != u2.id
```

[Correct output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a133/36)

Interchanging ON and WHERE gives the same result which is fine, but when I delete the WHERE I get more result:

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT u1.email
    FROM user u1
    LEFT JOIN user u2
    ON u1.email = u2.email
    AND u1.id != u2.id
```

[Incorrect output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a133/35)

Why is that ?

Comment: Adding the `u2.email` into the results will make it a little clearer what results you're getting: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a133/52 The `LEFT JOIN` is also returning those with null matches in the `ON` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in the first case the `where` clause is applied *after* the join and will remove all rows that were only included by the "outer" join. Those rows are removed because the `email` column from the `u2` table will be null for those and any comparison with `null` yields undefined which means that the `where` clause will discard those rows.

A `where` condition on an outer joined table essentially turns your outer join back into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your sqlfiddle isn't matching your code on this page.  Minor issue though.

Short answer is this: when you add a where clause that checks criteria on the left join, it essentially makes it act like an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a `LEFT JOIN`, you will get a row with values from `u1` and NULLs from `u2` if the `ON` clause doesn't hold. The `WHERE` clause however, applies to the entire result set so if `u2.id` turns out to be NULL, it will not be returned.

Changing `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the LEFT join and Selcting from Right Table Doesn't make sense.
if you use Left join and apply all conditions in JOIN clause you may see unexpected results. WHERE is filters applied after the JOIN results so unless your JOIN is INNER join switching conditions between JOIN and Where is not the same. JOIN will give more results.
but if JOIN is INNER JOIN then no matter where your conditions are you get same results.

in your example, if you just remove WHERE you are selecting ALL Distinct email but from u2. and as you have left join soem of non matching u2 rows will not be filter as they would have with WHERE clause.

Comment: it's a self join so i don't know that left-ness and right-ness make much difference.

Comment: you are using the same table but type of join is still LEFt OUTER JOIN. verbally when we say selef join it is indication that only one table involved in this join but what type of join is still depending on what you trying achive.